# VSCode Integration with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, web-development-server, visual-web-developer

I have made my website on VSC(HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT) from Scratch, can i publish my website as it is through WordPress without changing its layout or without building it again on WordPress? Basically i want to import my vscode website as it is on Wordpress.

is there any solution for the same, or we cannot do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish a site built like that on almost any web hosting service, by signing up and uploading your files. But possibly *not* on wordpress.com - I think they may only host sites built in Wordpress.